# Editing the invoice template in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, invoice

I need to edit the Woocommerce invoice template with coding. I Copied all the files from wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/templates/Simple to to my child them in wp-content/themes/church-event-child/woocommerce/pdf/yourtemplate and customized them there. I need the template like this:

Subtotal:       € 0

IVA:        € 0

---

Order total:        € 0

But woocommerce simple template only shows it like this

Subtotal:       € 0

---

Order total:        € 0

So it is about adding the IVA with the amount inside. Here you can see the code I am trying to change, but I dont know how to find where the label of the tax_amount is kept and how to display it right.

```
            <table class="totals">
                <tfoot>
                    <?php foreach( $this->get_woocommerce_totals() as $key => $total ) : ?>
                    <tr class="<?php echo $key; ?>">
                        <td class="no-borders"></td>
                        <th class="description"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                        <td class="price"><span class="totals-price"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

Thanks in Advance